# How to align the caption of a table to the left without hanging

Tags: tables, captions

i am trying to align a caption to the top left of my table and for every single table i will be using on my document, the problem is, i found here is this forum the solution for similar problems like this, but for me didn't work, the caption was aligning to the left of the document, so it would end up hanging, i couldn't find the solution, here is the code

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false
}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{
\footnotesize
\color{black}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Tabela 1]{Resultados experimentais para a luz vermelha.}
\label{Tabela 1}
\centering
\copyrightbox[b]{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & $S_0$ (mm) & $S_f$ (mm) & $\Delta s$ (mm) & $L=\frac{\Delta s}{10}$ & $2L$ & m & $\lambda$ (nm) \\ \hline
Medida 1 & 0,000 & 0,065 &  &  &  & 20 &  \\ \hline
Medida 2 & 0,003 & 0,072 &  &  &  & 20 &  \\ \hline
Medida 3 & 0,007 & 0,075 &  &  &  & 20 &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
{Fonte: elaborada pelo autor.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

By use of `threeparttable` and replace `copyrightbox` with `\multicolumn` cell at bottom of `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  skip=1ex,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false
}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption[Tabela 1]{Resultados experimentais para a luz vermelha.}
\label{Tabela 1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
    & $S_0$ (mm) & $S_f$ (mm) & $\Delta s$ (mm) & $L=\frac{\Delta s}{10}$ & $2L$ & m & $\lambda$ (nm) \\ \hline
Medida 1 & 0,000 & 0,065 &  &  &  & 20 &  \\ \hline
Medida 2 & 0,003 & 0,072 &  &  &  & 20 &  \\ \hline
Medida 3 & 0,007 & 0,075 &  &  &  & 20 &  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{8}{@{} >{\footnotesize}l}{Fonte: elaborada pelo autor.}
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```